# Slim how to take the post data from a form with file upload?

Tags: php, slim

How to take the post data using slim. i have a function call like this

`$this->app->post("/post/create", array($this, "createPost"));`
i want to get the post datas from a php html form. i took request like this

```
$request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
```

and took the post data like this

```
$userId = $_POST["user"];
$content = $_POST["content"];
$datetime = $_POST["date"];
$filename = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
$type = $_FILES["image"]["type"];
$size = $_FILES["image"]["size"];
$filetmpname = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
```

Is this the right way of doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
$this->app = new \Slim\Slim();

$this->app->post("/post/create", function () {

    $userId = $this->app->request->post('user');

    // or

    $allPostVars = $this->app->request->post();
    $userId = $allPostVars['user'];
    //...

});
```

if you dont want to use anonymous function ("*It is not possible to use $this from anonymous function before PHP 5.4.0*"), i think you can just do:

```
$this->app->post("/post/create", 'createPost');


function createPost() {
        $userId = $this->app->request->post('user');
        //...
}
```

Answer (score 9):

if you use Slim 3.*  you could do it like this:

```
$app->post('/users', function ($request, $response) {
   $formDataArry = $request->getParsedBody();
    // do something with formDataArry 
});
```

Comment: from getParsedBody can we obtain the fileuploaded as well...?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Slim 3:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Product\Classes;

use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

class LoginController
{
  public function loginUser(Request $request, Response $response)
  {
        $username = $request->getParam('username');
        $password = $request->getParam('password');

        // Logic to validate login ommited.
  }
}
```